# hook_path_update (and insert and delete) not getting called

Tags: 7, path-aliases, uri

I've added the following methods to my module, saved, and flushed all caches on my site. I have double checked that my module is enabled and working properly in all other respects.

```
function xxxxxxx_path_insert($path) {
  kpr($path);
  var_dump($path);
}

function xxxxxxx_path_update($path) {
  kpr($path);
  var_dump($path);
}

function xxxxxxx_path_delete($path) {
  kpr($path);
  var_dump($path);
}
```

I want to receive notifications when content path aliases are updated so that I can store some info about them for my custom module. I just put these shell methods in place to ensure I was getting the hook calls and to double check the structure of the $path variable.

Then I edited an existing piece of content. I changed the title and saved the node. Since I'm also using pathauto, that module updated the content path alias to point to a new url based on the new title. I did not receive any of the calls.

Ok, so I figured maybe the auto generation of the alias was the problem, so I edited the piece of content, disabled the auto generation of the path alias and changed the path alias to something by hand. Then saved the node. I did not receive any of the calls to the above hooks.

What am I doing wrong? Why aren't these hooks getting called?

The hook documentation for your reference: [path.api.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!path!path.api.php/7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*sigh* I flushed all caches a TON of times and it would never call my hooks. I had to completely disable my module, flush all caches, and then re-enable my module.

Then the system saw my hooks.

*sigh*